# fine subcaption legend placement

Tags: floats, subcaption

I am having trouble trying to put the subcaption legends at the top of the figures. No matter what I do, they show up in the middle.
This code reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[draft, oneside, a4paper, onecolumn, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \adjustbox{minipage=1em,valign=t}{\subcaption{} \label{fig:fig1}}%
   \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.24\textwidth}
   \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1.]{fig1.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
  \adjustbox{minipage=1em,valign=t}{\subcaption{} \label{fig:fig2}}%
   \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.24\textwidth}
   \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1.]{fig2.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}
  \adjustbox{minipage=0em,valign=t}{\subcaption{} \label{fig:fig3}}%
   \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
   \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=1.]{fig3.pdf}  \\
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried without `adjustbox`?

Comment: It doesn't work. The objective is to place the label on the side (on top) so I can save space above and below.

Comment: Try `\captionsetup[sub]{position=top}`, but the `\adjustbox` does no good there, in my point of view

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: You are aligning the top of the caption [t] to the center of the subfigure [c].  Also, the top of a minipage is actually the baseline of the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to align the centers of the subfigures together, but align the tops of the captions to the tops of the subfigures, you need to first determine the height of the subfigures using saveboxes.

BTW, without a caption a subfigure **is** a minipage.

```
\documentclass[draft, oneside, a4paper, onecolumn, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \sbox0{\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.24\textwidth}
   \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1.]{fig1.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}}%
  \adjustbox{minipage=1em,raise=\dimexpr\ht0-\height}{\subcaption{} \label{fig:fig1}}%
  \usebox0
%
  \sbox0{\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.24\textwidth}
   \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1.]{fig2.pdf}
  \end{subfigure}}%
  \adjustbox{minipage=1em,raise=\dimexpr\ht0-\height}{\subcaption{} \label{fig:fig2}}%
  \usebox0
%
  \sbox0{\begin{subfigure}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
   \centering
      \includegraphics[scale=1.]{fig3.pdf}  \\
  \end{subfigure}}%
  \adjustbox{minipage=1em,raise=\dimexpr\ht0-\height}{\subcaption{} \label{fig:fig3}}%
  \usebox0
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

If you want to align the tops of the images, one can use a much simpler approach.

```
\documentclass[draft, oneside, a4paper, onecolumn, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \adjustbox{minipage=2em,raise=-\height}{\subcaption{} \label{fig:fig1}}%
  \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1.]{fig1.pdf}}
%
  \adjustbox{minipage=2em,raise=-\height}{\subcaption{} \label{fig:fig2}}%
  \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1.2]{fig2.pdf}}
%
  \adjustbox{minipage=2em,raise=-\height}{\subcaption{} \label{fig:fig3}}%
  \raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[scale=1.]{fig3.pdf}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo 2]

Comment: You're saying that the way I use it, I could just replace subfigure with minipage and I would get the same result?

Comment: Yup.  I already tried it.  If you want to align bottoms,  you really don't need a minipage either. (Captions, OTOH, do require minipages.)

Comment: You solved the issue. I would expect, however, that this should be a functionality within the subcaption package itself. Why is this not possible within the package? It feels like a hack to make it work this way.

Comment: Normally one aligns baselines, which are set for each box independently. It should also be mentioned that minipage [t] means the baseline of the first line, not the actual top. For that one usually uses \raisebox{-\height}{...}.

Comment: If I wanted to, is there a way to move vertically a bit the final labels? I am getting the issue that whenever two figures don't have the same height the labels are also not aligned.

Comment: That didn't work. You mean the subfigures right? Something like `\sbox0{\begin{subfigure}[b]`?